# save verfied phone number from firebase auth ui phone number authentication system

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Is there a way that I could get the phone number that the user typed in after they are verified. I need to save the phone number and make it into a cookie so I can use the phone number for a google maps marker label. I posted the same question on a GitHub forum and another user replied saying that I need to include this code.`firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber`But I'm not sure where to implement this so I included my auth page HTML and javascript code. If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.
[image]

```js
/**
 * @return {!Object} The FirebaseUI config.
 */
function getUiConfig() {
  return {
    'callbacks': {
      // Called when the user has been successfully signed in.

      'signInSuccess': function(user, credential, redirectUrl) {
        handleSignedInUser(user);
        // Do not redirect.
        //'signInSuccessUrl': "http://localhost:8080/CurrentLocation.html",
        return true;
      }
    },
    // Opens IDP Providers sign-in flow in a popup.
    'signInSuccessUrl':  "http://localhost:8080/homepage_latest.html",
    'signInFlow': 'popup',
    'signInOptions': [
      // The Provider you need for your app. We need the Phone Auth
      //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        recaptchaParameters: {
          type: 'image', // another option is 'audio'
          size: 'invisible', // other options are 'normal' or 'compact'
          badge: 'bottomleft' // 'bottomright' or 'inline' applies to invisible.
        }
      }
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    'tosUrl': 'https://www.google.com'
  };
}

// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

/**
 * Displays the UI for a signed in user.
 * @param {!firebase.User} user
 */
var handleSignedInUser = function(user) {
  document.getElementById('user-signed-in').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('user-signed-out').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('name').textContent = user.displayName;
  document.getElementById('email').textContent = user.email;
  document.getElementById('phone').textContent = user.phoneNumber;
  if (user.photoURL){
    document.getElementById('photo').src = user.photoURL;
    document.getElementById('photo').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('photo').style.display = 'none';
  }
};


/**
 * Displays the UI for a signed out user.
 */
var handleSignedOutUser = function() {
  document.getElementById('user-signed-in').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('user-signed-out').style.display = 'block';
  ui.start('#firebaseui-container', getUiConfig());
};

// Listen to change in auth state so it displays the correct UI for when
// the user is signed in or not.
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('loaded').style.display = 'block';
  user ? handleSignedInUser(user) : handleSignedOutUser();
});

/**
 * Deletes the user's account.
 */
var deleteAccount = function() {
  firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().catch(function(error) {
    if (error.code == 'auth/requires-recent-login') {
      // The user's credential is too old. She needs to sign in again.
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        // The timeout allows the message to be displayed after the UI has
        // changed to the signed out state.
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert('Please sign in again to delete your account.');
        }, 1);
      });
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Initializes the app.
 */
var initApp = function() {
  document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  });
  document.getElementById('delete-account').addEventListener(
      'click', function() {
        deleteAccount();
      });
};

window.addEventListener('load', initApp);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <link href="auth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>



 <div id="container">
      <h3></h3>
      <div id="loading"></div>
      <div id="loaded" class="hidden">
        <div id="main">
          <div id="user-signed-in" class="hidden">
            <div id="user-info">
              <div id="photo-container">
                <img id="photo">
              </div>
              <div id="name"></div>
              <div id="email"></div>
              <div id="phone"></div>
               <script>
             </script>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <p>
              <button id="sign-out">Sign Out</button>
              <button id="delete-account">Delete account</button>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="user-signed-out" class="hidden">
            <h4>You are signed out.</h4>
            <div id="firebaseui-spa">

              <h3></h3>
              <div id="firebaseui-container"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="auth.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward:

```
'signInSuccess': function(user, credential, redirectUrl) {
    // You can also access this via firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber
    console.log(user.phoneNumber);
    handleSignedInUser(user);
    // Do not redirect.
    //'signInSuccessUrl': "http://localhost:8080/CurrentLocation.html",
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: For some reason the marker label says PhoneNumber=undefined; +1########## so it displays the number but it also includes something that says undefined. I used 'firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber'.